How to write join by Lateral "," in Java Criteria API JPA, Hibernate
I want to achieve the below result with ','
FROM table1 t1,
  LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(secret_data->'rating'->'subRating') AS subRatings
WHERE

I want to achieve this with the Criteria API. I know we can create a lateralJoinSubquery and add it in this way:
JpaDerivedJoin<Object> lateralJoin =
            ((SqmRoot<Table1>) Root).joinLateral(lateralJoinSubquery);

But this will yield:
table1 t1 JOIN LATERAL (The subquery)

which I do not want.

Hibernates derived roots feature might be of help here - https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.3/querylanguage/html_single/Hibernate_Query_Language.html#derived-root

Nope @SpaceTrucker
